# Deploying Azure Cloud Service targeting .NET Framework 4.6

Tags: .net, azure

Details:

- I have Azure App Service Tools v2.9.6 installed.
- My cloud configuration specifies osFamily="5" (Windows Server 2016)
- osVersion="*"

> The SDK package you are trying to deploy is not supported by the
>   operating system you have chosen. The operating system you are trying
>   to deploy to is: Windows Server 2016. Verify osFamily and/or osVersion
>   settings in your .cscfg file.

According to [this document from MS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-guestos-update-matrix), this should be supported. How do I get this service deployed?

Answer (score 3):

It turns out that this project was created with Azure SDK 2.8. To get the project to build with the updated SDK, I had to change the following line in my .ccproj file:

```
<CloudExtensionsDir Condition=" '$(CloudExtensionsDir)' == '' ">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\Windows Azure Tools\2.8\</CloudExtensionsDir>
```

to:

```
<CloudExtensionsDir Condition=" '$(CloudExtensionsDir)' == '' ">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\Windows Azure Tools\2.9\</CloudExtensionsDir>
```

It's basically following the reverse of the procedure [outlined here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8701b03a-804f-4953-9ea0-01064aa4dc16/downgrade-from-18-tools-to-17?forum=azuretfs).